# ZedGraph: Changing behavior of Set Scale to Default

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have plotted few graphs using ZedGraphs. Now, i have an option that user can plot some graphs using different check boxes a can remove them as well. But, i am not scaling the graph when user makes those graphs as i don't want to change the look of the graphs.

Now, if the user zooms and then click to the Set Scale to Default, the graphs got reset as there is a call to AxisChange() i guess.

But, i want the original look of the graphs that i have plotted and not the default view which changes the view completely.

S, is there any way where i can change the behavior of the Set Scale to Default functionality?

Comment: The `Undo all zoom/pan` menu do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options to try with,

1. Get rid off the default context menu item(Set Scale to Default) & add your own custom context menu item.

   In-order to remove:

   ```
   private void zedGraphControl1_ContextMenuBuilder(
       ZedGraphControl sender, ContextMenuStrip menuStrip, 
       Point mousePt, ZedGraphControl.ContextMenuObjectState objState)
   {
       foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuStrip.Items)
       {
           if ((string)item.Tag == "set_default")
           {
               menuStrip.Items.Remove(item);
               break;
           }
        }
   }
   ```

   and to add a new item: http://www.smallguru.com/2009/06/zedgraph-csharp-graph-data-export-to-cs/
2. Edit the source code (It's a bit tricky but do-able)

   I don't see any easy way to change the behavior of the pre-build options.

Comment: A more complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/ZedGraph/ZedGraph/wiki/Edit-the-Context-Menu).